# Join two numbers to create a new number composed of integer and decimal part

Tags: javascript, string, integer, numbers, rounding

I have two numbers and I need to convert them into a number composed of an integer part and a decimal part.

I'm having problems because the number that represents the integer part can be 0 or -0

I thought of something like that but the result still doesn't get the 0 sign. I thought of using Math.sign but it returns 0 if it's 0 or -0.

```
const i = -0
const f = 20

const value = parseFloat(i.toString() + "." + f.toString())

console.log(value)
```

Comment: "I thought of using Math.sign but it returns 0 if it's 0 or -0." No, `Math.sign(-0)` returns `-0` — but then you're back in the same boat. The problem is that detecting `-0` is very hard: there is only a couple sure-fire ways in JavaScript to do it: `Object.is(number, -0)` is one; dividing to get `-Infinity` is another.  ([`number.toLocaleString()`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-number.prototype.tolocalestring) is implementation-dependent, and therefore unreliable.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in js this is expected

```js
// Positive and negative zero are equal to each other in JavaScript:
console.log(+0 === -0) // true
console.log(+0 == -0) // true

// Note that +0 is the same as 0:
console.log(+0) // 0
console.log(0 === -0) // true
console.log(0 == -0) // true
```

This behavior comes from ECMAScript section 7.2.13

So to differentiate you should use Object.is: (ES6+)

```js
console.log(+0 === -0) // true
console.log(Object.is(+0,-0)) // false


function makeN(i,f){
    return  (i + f / 100) * (Object.is(i,-0)?-1:1);
}

console.log(makeN(-0,20)); //-0.20
console.log(makeN(0,20)); //0.20
```

Using ES5 or below you can use -Infinity
as 1/-0 produce -Infinity

```js
console.log(1/-0) // -Infinity
console.log(1/-0 === -Infinity) // true

function makeN(i,f){
    return  (i + f / 100) * (1/i === -Infinity?-1:1);
}

console.log(makeN(-0,20)); //-0.20
console.log(makeN(0,20)); //0.20
```

A solution not limited to 2 decimal place
Using jsbench.me, toString + parseFloat is like 93% slower than the following solution

```js
function makeN(i,f){
    return  (i + f / (Math.pow(10,f.toString().length))) * (Object.is(i,-0)?-1:1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to check if the number is a zero negative:

```
const i = -0
const f = 20

const sign = isZeroNegative(i) ? '-' : '';
const value = parseFloat(sign + i.toString() + "." + f.toString())

console.log(value)

function isZeroNegative(zero) {
  if (zero !== 0) return false;
  return zero.toLocaleString()[0] === "-";
}
```

[Source](https://dev.to/emnudge/identifying-negative-zero-2j1o)

Comment: This is not reliable. For example, to see what people in Egypt would experience, try `(-0).toLocaleString('ar-EG')`: it is not `"-0"`. You could use `zero.toLocaleString('en-US')`, but even then the specification says that "it is permissible, but not encouraged, for it to return the same thing as `toString`." It works in most browsers; are you sure it works in all?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't considered that! The solution from Christian seems to be way better.